# Rewrite rule to a port number

Tags: url-rewriting, httpserver

Help me out in  writing a reroute engine where the request to the following url http://example.com/Hello is routed to http://example.com:81/Hello in IBM HTTP Server.

Tks for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a client asks for a webpage, the default port is port 80. If you would like to redirect the traffic to port 81, then you can do something called "port forwarding". Port forwarding is where you can tell your internet machine to "forward" all requests for port *x* to port *y*. If your internet machine is a router, then you can usually set up  port forwarding by connecting to your router and there should be options for port forwarding.

Comment: Do we have any other option. other than port forwarding. Either rewrite rule or proxy pass. Will try this one.